# Can you add an attribute to an implicit async void method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Because `async void` methods can be dangerous I mark them with an attribute `[AsyncVoid]` and when starting the application I check using reflection that all `async void` methods have this attribute, so I did not miss one because they can be hard to find. For instance, this is a hidden implicit `async void` method:

```
backgroundWorker.DoWork += async (sender, args) => await HandleFrames()
```

Is there a way to add the `[AsyncVoid]` attribute to this hidden `async void` method? Like for instance:

```
backgroundWorker.DoWork += [AsyncVoid] async (sender, args) => await HandleFrames()
```

Comment: Why? What purpose does this serve?

Comment: Instead of using an implicit event handler, define one explicitly (for example `void FrameHandlerAsync(object sender, 
    DoWorkEventArgs e)`, and decorate that with the `[AsyncVoid]` attirbute.

Comment: Why do you do this "when starting the application" rather than in a unit test, out of interest?

Comment: @JonSkeet: you are right, I will move it to the unit test.

Comment: Why not look for usages of `AsyncVoidMethodBuilder` as in http://jaylee.org/post/2012/07/08/c-sharp-async-tips-and-tricks-part-2-async-void.aspx ?

Comment: @TamásSzabó: I did not show it in the example for reasons of space, but the real call to HandleFrames has some closure parameters.

Comment: @Ben: As said I find the use of async void methods using reflection, but I add an attribute to each async void method to signal that I have inspected it for potential problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there isn't. From the C# 5.0 specs (§17.2, page 417):

> Attributes can be specified at global scope (to specify attributes on
>   the containing assembly or module) and for *type-declarations* (§9.6),
>   *class-member-declarations* (§10.1.5), *interface-member-declarations*
>   (§13.2), *struct-member-declarations* (§11.2), *enum-member-declarations*
>   (§14.3), *accessor-declarations* (§10.7.2), *event-accessor-declarations*
>   (§10.8.1), and *formal-parameter-lists* (§10.6.1).

So no attributes can be defined for anonymous methods (or classes, for that matter).